# How can you use Q&A to gain good Karma and also aid to realize liberation

Tags: karma

How can you use Q&A to:

- effectively and efficiently create good Karma, and
- also use it as an aid to reach the final Buddhist goal

Also what Suttas and literature, cover these topics?

Comment: Just avoid getting attached to points and reputation! Lol. That was just a joke :)  I think by providing good answers you are helping others therefore creating good Kamma! "The gift of Dhamma excels all other gifts"

Comment: too broad, too opinion based IMO.

Comment: Not really broad as I don't expect too many places where the Buddha discussed something along these lines. At most a few Suttas at the most.

Comment: Oh so you mean Buddhist perspective on questions and answers in general, not just StackExchange Q&A.

Comment: Yes. With the Karmic and liberation implementations of Q&A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How can you use Q&A to gain good Karma and also aid to realize liberation?

By reflecting on a few principles when asking & answering:

***Asking & Answering***

Notice in what category does the question lie in:

> "There are these four ways of answering questions. Which four? There
>   are questions that should be answered categorically [straightforwardly
>   yes, no, this, that]. There are questions that should be answered with
>   an analytical (qualified) answer [defining or redefining the terms].
>   There are questions that should be answered with a counter-question.
>   There are [questions that should be put aside](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn44/sn44.intro.than.html). These are the four ways
>   of answering questions."
>   <sub>*-[AN 4.42, Questions](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.042.than.html)*</sub>

And if the answers given are appropriate to that kind of question:

> "Monks, it's through his way of participating in a discussion that a
>   person can be known as fit to talk with or unfit to talk with. If a
>   person, when asked a question, doesn't give a categorical answer to a
>   question deserving a categorical answer, doesn't give an analytical
>   (qualified) answer to a question deserving an analytical answer,
>   doesn't give a counter-question to a question deserving a
>   counter-question, doesn't put aside a question deserving to be put
>   aside, then — that being the case — he is a person unfit to talk with.
>   But if a person, when asked a question, gives a categorical answer to
>   a question deserving a categorical answer, gives an analytical answer
>   to a question deserving an analytical answer, gives a counter-question
>   to a question deserving a counter-question, and puts aside a question
>   deserving to be put aside, then — that being the case — he is a person
>   fit to talk with.
>   <sub>*-[AN 3.67, Topics for Discussion](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.067.than.html)* *(I recommend reading the entire discourse since it has additional valuable advice. You might also want to read [Bhikkhu Bodhi's translation](http://lirs.ru/lib/sutra/The_Numerical_Discourses_of_the_Buddha,Anguttara_Nikaya,Bodhi,2012.pdf#page=287))*</sub>

Notice that not all questions deserve an answer since they are off-topic or have implicit assumptions which makes them so. [Here](http://www.shin-ibs.edu/documents/pwj3-9/02Karunadasa39.pdf)'s an article regarding this kind of questions which I think is worth reading.

***Asking***

When asking, be aware of the motive behind your question:

> Ven. Sariputta said: "All those who ask questions of another do so
>   from any one of five motivations. Which five?
>
> "One asks a question of another through stupidity & bewilderment. One
>   asks a question of another through evil desires & overwhelmed with
>   greed. One asks a question of another through contempt. One asks a
>   question of another when desiring knowledge. Or one asks a question
>   with this thought, 'If, when asked, he answers correctly, well &
>   good. If not, then I will answer correctly [for him].'
>
> "All those who ask questions of another do so from any one of these
>   five motivations. And as for me, when I ask a question of another,
>   it's with this thought: 'If, when asked, he answers correctly, well &
>   good. If not, then I will answer correctly [for him].'
>   <sub>*-[AN 5.165, On Asking Questions](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.165.than.html)*</sub>

---

For a broader and more in-depth understanding of this topic, I recommend reading the related discourses which are mentioned at the end of the discourses linked above and a brilliant book written by *Thanissaro Bhikkhu* named *[Skill in Questions: How the Buddha Taught](http://www.dhammatalks.org/Archive/Writings/skillInQuestions_v140109.pdf)*. It has many examples of Q&A's that fit the above categories.

Comment: Well said indeed. Good answer.

Comment: One thing you can add is the Karmic and liberation angle for completeness. This was what I was looking for. Nevertheless a very good answer.

Comment: Keep this accepted for the time. But would be great to have the karma and liberation angle.

Comment: I think there is no such explicit relationship in the discourses. However, one can understand that by knowing the motivations & the categories of questions, one will be communicating more effectively or, in other words, "making good karma". One can avoid a lot of confusion and misunderstanding by being clear on the motivation, what kind of topics are worth discussing and with whom. These kind of distinctions really help one avoid unskillful speech. The above discourse, AN 3.67, is very rich in these kind of distinctions. One can definitely see the *karma* aspect of it there.

Comment: Many be you can merge this information also. Also Ven. Thanisaro has written a book called Karma in Questions. I have not read it or looked at the content. Perhaps this might have some additional information?

Comment: What is the name / title of the referenced Sutta in your comment?

Comment: I've read it a long time ago. It's an older book (2002) with many essays. He mentions some of those essays in the book I mentioned above. It seems that *Skill in Questions* is a more mature and organized book. I think the content may overlap, but I'm not sure. If you want to read that booklet and add an answer with what you find in it, feel free.

Comment: Maybe the book I mentioned might not have much though the title suggested some karmic connection.

Comment: Just saw your newer comment.